# Ways to search and tag a MongoDB database of academic papers

Tags: python, mongodb, search, lucene

Apologies for the vague nature of this question but I'm honestly not quite sure where to start and thought I'd ask here for guidance.

As an exercise, I've downloaded several academic papers and stored them as plain text in a mongoDB database.

I'd like to do write a search feature (using Python, R, whatever) that when you enter text and returns the most relevant articles. Clearly, *relevant* is really hard -- that's what google got so right.

However, I'm not looking for it to be perfect. Just to get something. A few thoughts I had were:

1) Simple MongoDB full text search

2) Implement Lucene Search

3) Tag them (unsure how though) and then return them sorted by the most number of tags?

Is there a solution someone has used that's out of the box and works fairly well? I can always optimize the search feature later -- for now I just want all the pieces to move together...

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends. I'd vote for MongoDB full-text search & Lucene (or Lucene based engines like elastic search). the full text search engine provides you basic search features, match score. And can be a good choice if you want to start quickly and want less maintenance. You may want to check the supported language first. You can start from here and maybe migrate to Lucene later when your project runs further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a solution someone has used that's out of the box and works fairly well?

It depends on how you define *well*, but in simple terms, I'd say no. There is just no single and accurate definition of *fairly well*. A lot of challenges intrinsic to a particular problem arise when one trying to implement a *good search algorithm*. Those challenges lies in:

- users needs diversity. Users in different fields have different intentions and as a result different expectation from a search result page;
- natural languages diversity, if you are trying to implement multi-language search (German has a lot of noun compounds, Russian has enormous flexion variability etc.);

There are some algorithms that are proven to work *better than others* though, thus are good to start from. [TF*IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and [BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) two most popular.

> I can always optimize the search feature later -- for now I just want all the pieces to move together...

MongoDB or any RDBMS with fulltext indexing support is good enough for a proof-of-concept, but if you need to optimize for search performance, you will need an inverted index (Solr/Lucene). From Solr/Lucene you will get ability to manage:

- how exactly words are stemmed (this is important to solve [undersemming/overstemming problems](http://www.dtsearch.co.uk/support/WebHelp/ST100/Evaluation_of_stemming_performance.htm));
- what the word is. Is "supercomputer" one word? What about "stackoverflow" or "OutOfBoundsException"?
- synonyms and word expansion (should "O<sub>2</sub>" be found for a "oxygen" query?)
- how exactly search is performed. Which words could be ignored during search. Which ones are required to be found. Which one are required to be found near each other (think of search phrase: "not annealed" or "without expansion").

This is just what comes to mind first.

So if you are planning to work these things out I definitely recommend Lucene as a framework or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)/[ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co) as a search system if you need to build proof-of-concept fast. If not, MongoDB/RDMS will work well.